# Creating a mix and max function

Tags: lua

I have a function which tells me if there is a crossover between sources (not allowed) between elements for two vendors. I won't go into how this is constructed as it will require a lot of explanation  and I'm trying to keep this simple. All you need to know is that it takes two concatenated vendor names and returns true/false if they have no overlap or do (respectively).
E.g.

```
noCrossover["TescoSainsburys"] = true
```

Now, I want to find the best combination of stores to get a product A, without calling the source multiple times. For just two stores, this is easy (I have a table constructed earlier which contains vendors already):

```
vendorsCalled = {"Tesco", "Sainsburys"}

if noCrossover[vendorsCalled[1] .. vendorsCalled[2]] then
    numProductsAgr = tescoProductA + sainsburysProductA
else
    numProductsAgr = math.max(tescoProductA, sainsburysProductA)
end
```

However, as I increase the number of vendors, it gets more complex:

```
vendorsCalled = {"Tesco", "Sainsburys", Waitrose"}
```

```
if  noCrossover[vendorsCalled[1] .. vendorsCalled[2]] and
    noCrossover[vendorsCalled[1] .. vendorsCalled[3]] and
    noCrossover[vendorsCalled[2] .. vendorsCalled[3]] then
        numProductsAgr123 = tescoProductA + sainsburysProductA + waitroseProductA
    else 
        numProductsAgr123 = 0
end 
if noCrossover[vendorsCalled[1] .. vendorsCalled[2]] then
    numProductsAgr12 = tescoProductA + sainsburysProductA
else
    numProductsAgr12 = math.max(tescoProductA, sainsburysProductA)
end
if noCrossover[vendorsCalled[1] .. vendorsCalled[3]] then
    numProductsAgr13 = tescoProductA + waitroseProductA
else
    numProductsAgr13= math.max(tescoProductA, waitroseProductA)
end  
if noCrossover[vendorsCalled[2] .. vendorsCalled[3]] then
    numProductsAgr23 = sainsburysProductA + waitroseProductA
else
    numProductsAgr23 = math.max(sainsburysProductA + waitroseProductA)
end
numResidencyMatchesAgr = math.max(numProductsAgr123 , numProductsAgr12 , numProductsAgr13 , numProductsAgr23 )
```

and it gets harder again with 4.

It's also worth noting that these are used in different places (1,2,3,4 stores) so I can use separate functions for each where I define how many stores are used.

I also need to be able to work out which vendors my final number steams from

**Is there a better, more concise way of doing this to avoid needing to write out these log error prone scripts?**

Comment: Is it possible for `tescoProductA` and such to be negative?

Comment: They can be 0 or not exist, but never negative